# Naming items in Value clause for readability

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a better way to achieve mapping items in the `values` to column names. I always do this using comments:

```
insert into Table1 (Col1, Col2, ..., Coln)
values ('One' /* Col1 */, 'Two' /* Col2 */, ..., 'ValN' /* Coln */);
```

It becomes especially important when there are many columns involved and the values clause has queries in it. I always have to count and see which item in the `values` clause is for which column. Therefore, I just use comments as shown above. I will state the obvious that sometimes depending on the query, I may keep them on separate lines.

Any other way?

Comment: Depending on the query complexity variables (@) could be a way to improve readability/discoverability. Obviously, there are situations where this approach would make the TSQL more complicated.

Comment: I agree and I try to do that as well.

Comment: Ususually if I get the urge to label items in a `VALUES` clause as it is not clear without then I just replace it with a `SELECT` without a `FROM` as the values in the `SELECT` can have column aliases. They need to be combined with `UNION ALL` if multiple rows.

Comment: Similar to Martin's approach `INSERT INTO t1(co1, col2..)SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('One','Two')) AS D(Col1, Col2);` Wrap the VALUES with and provide explicit column names.

Comment: @martinsmith That's a great tip! I will definitely put that into use. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a good way. I usually use one line for each column. It can get really long but I find it more readable. Something like this:

```
insert into Table1 (
 Col1 
,Col2 
,...
,Coln
)
values (
 One  /* Col1 */ 
,Two  /* Col2 */ 
,... 
,ValN /* Coln */
);
```

In some cases, using a JSON string could be useful. In other cases it maybe an overkill. Here's a simple example:

Let's say we have a table called "test" with two columns: "Number" (INT) and "Word" (VARCHAR(40))

We can insert records in that table using the following construction:

```
INSERT INTO test (Number, Word)
  SELECT source.Number, source.Word
  FROM
  (
  SELECT  Number, Word
      FROM
      OpenJson('[{
    "number": 01,  "word": "This"
  }, {
    "number": 02,  "word": "Is"
  }, {
    "number": 03,  "word": "Just"
  }, {
    "number": 04,  "word": "a"
  }, {        
    "number": 05,  "word": "Test"
  }] '
  ) WITH (Number INT '$.number', Word VARCHAR(40) '$.word') 

  ) AS source
```

As we can see:

1. The data to insert is stored inside the JSON string. We then name the each property in the JSON string using the same column names in the table.
2. When doing the actual insert, the names of the values to insert are variables that have the same name than their columns, making it very readable. (source.Number, source.Word).

In some cases, using the JSON string can help out not only with the mapping of the data and their columns but also debugging the data and finding wrong values.

Comment: I already do the same. I am looking for another way, if there is one, as indicated in the question.

Comment: Yes, I just added another way using a JSON string as the source of the data. In some cases this approach could work and help with readability and debugging.@CodingYoshi